# How to relate a backend pid to a windows application?

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I have postgres database that has two windows processes connected to it. One is a powershell script, the other is a c# application. Both processes run on the same box accessing the same database.

I have occasional locking problems, checking in pg_locks will give me the blocked and blocking pids.

If I look on windows task manager I can see that both of these pids have the process name 'postgres.exe'

How can I tell which pid refers to the poweshell process, and which to the c# app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app (or script) can tell you its pid using the function [`pg_backend_pid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html)

```
select pg_backend_pid();
```

Alternatively, you can set different `application_name` parameters in your apps and report this using [`pg_stat_activity,`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS) e.g.:

```
set application_name to 'my_distinct_name';

select l.*, a.application_name
from pg_locks l
join pg_stat_activity a using (pid);
```